# Can Barrington's Theorem be used to speed up computation of some function ? How?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

How can [Barrington's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29#Barrington.27s_theorem) be used to obtain faster programs ? Assuming, I want to evaluate function greater than *gt* between two bits *x* and *y*, defined as $gt(x,y)=xy+x$, equal with $1$ when $x$ is greater than $y$. Now, let's say I have two numbers on $N$ bits and the problem expands.

Can Barrington theorem be applied to speed up computation ? Or not necessary speed the computation, but reduce the number of multiplications of the boolean circuit implementing the *greater than* function for two numbers on $N$ bits ?

Comment: It seems pretty much impossible to practically speed up much of anything using Barrington's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Barrington's theorem probably isn't going to be useful to speed up computation.  Rather, it's a useful way to understand the power of different computing models.  For instance, it has been used to [prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29#Barrington.27s_theorem) facts about what can be computed with log-depth circuits.  It has also been used as a tool in building fully homomorphic cryptosystems.